# Prevent orphaned or widowed list items

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have a document that consists of a series of:

**heading**

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
  ...

Where the number of bullets under each heading is as few as 2, but can be at least 8 in the largest example I've found so far.

What I want is to prevent fewer than two bullets on a page (assume no bullet is so long that this would be impossible). These would not be allowed.

**heading**
 - bullet 1
[page break]
 - bullet 2
 - bullet 3

or

**heading**
 - bullet 1
 - bullet 2
[page break]
 - bullet 3

In a list of a 4 items, a 2/2 split would be OK, otherwise all items must be on the same page.

The heading has "Widow/Orphan control", "Keep with next", and "Keep lines together" on, and every list item has "Widow/Orphan control" and "Keep lines together" on.

Obviously I can't turn on "keep with next" for every list item, since that would not only keep the entire list on the same page always, but it will also try to keep the entire next list together (effectively forcing a page break before the first heading), since the last list item has to be "kept with next" (which is the heading, which must be kept with next... etc).

I could write a custom style and apply it to the first two and last two list items, but if the lists ever change, that would be a problem.

I doubt this is really possible, but in case I'm missing some clever trick, I'm asking for any ideas anyone has.

Comment: What about a bit of code to automate this task and to generate a docx file without vba.

Comment: I'm composing it as I go. Basically it's a list of responsibilities: [Person 1 - task a, task b, task c...] repeated. At the point at which I script anything to do it, I've probably wasted as much time as it would take to just check over it when it's done. Subsequent edits will probably be minimal (or not my problem :D).